# Call script at specific screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery

Any idea about how to get the script below working only on a >767 screen size?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).fadeThis({
        baseName: "slide-",
        speed: 500, 
        easing: "easeOutCubic",
        offset: 0, 
        reverse: false, 
        distance: 50, 
        scrolledIn: null, 
        scrolledOut: null
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS for this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width:767px)"  href="yourcssfilefor767.css" type="text/css">
```

If you have to do this dynamically:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).on("change", function(){
       if($(window).width() > 767){
         //do stuff here
       }
    });
});
</script>
```